# Storing member function in a vector and ensuring object still exists when invoked later

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, std-function, object-lifetime

I have a class `X` and I want to pass a member function `bar` to another class `Y`, which will store it in a vector and invoke it at some other time.

I understand that I need to make sure that `X` still exists when `Y` invokes the function. How do I do that?

In my example below, I **initially** thought that if I passed a shared_ptr to `bar` this would do what I want - i.e. as long as `Y` exists, then so will `X`, as `Y` holds a shared_ptr to one of its member functions.

I'm pretty sure now that this logic is incorrect. Can someone please enlighten me?

```
class Y {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>> m_v;
public:
  void foo(const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>& callback) {
    m_v.push_back(callback);
  }

  void sometime_later() {
    // invoke call back function in vector
    // how do I ensure the object I want to call the function on still exists
  }
};

class X {
  Y& m_y;
public:
  X(Y& y) : m_y(y) {
    m_y.foo(std::make_shared<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(&X::bar, this)));
  }

  void bar() {
    // do some stuff
  }
};
```

Comment: Couldnt you use more expressive names than foo , bar, X and Y to make the code more readable and the idea more understandable?

Comment: You are correct, holding a `shared_ptr` to a `std::function` to which a member function of an `X` has been bound has no influence on the lifetime of the `X` instance at all. Without some context of what you're ultimately trying to do it's a bit difficult to recommend a solution.

Comment: I don't think that the vector of `std::shared_ptr` will do what you want. You are sharing a `std::function` and not instances of `X`. You should think about what `std::shared_ptr` will delete when it gets deleted itself.

Comment: @A.S.H I think the idea is pretty understandable as it is. The question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the design to resolve my lifetime issue.

Rather than declaring a vector as follows:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>>
```

and issuing a call on the stored function sometime later, I declare it as:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>>
```

and then place a requirement on the object X to implement a named function (in my example above it woyuld be `bar`) and then call it at the appropriate time. That way I ensure X exists when the callback function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using `std::enable_shared_from_this` in conjunction with `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class Y {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>> m_v;
public:
    void foo(const std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>& callback) {
      m_v.push_back(callback);
    }

    void sometime_later(){
        for (const auto& f: m_v) {
            (*f)();
        }
    }
};

class X : public std::enable_shared_from_this<X> {
  Y& m_y;
  std::function<void()> m_callback;
public:
  X(Y& y) : m_y(y), m_callback(std::bind(&X::bar, this)) {
  }

  void add()
  {
    m_y.foo(std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>>{shared_from_this(), &m_callback});
    std::cout << shared_from_this().use_count() << "\n";
  }

  void bar() {
      std::cout << shared_from_this().use_count();
  }
};
int main(){

    Y y;
    {
        auto x = std::make_shared<X>(y);
        x->add();
    }
    y.sometime_later();
}
```

[LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f3111a5e8c71bd5)

Comment: Gotta run now, but I will add more details if you need later